# passing methods that accepts blocks

Tags: ruby, closures

How is a good way of passing a method that accept a block?

I.e. to treat the method as a variable so it could be used in this way:

```
(@glob&.each || crawl_dir(@base_dir)) do |file|
        puts "#{file}"
      end
```

A simple example that can be tried out:

```rb
> require 'csv'
=> true

> CSV {|v|v}
=> <#CSV io_type:$stdout encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"">

> a=CSV
=> CSV

> a==CSV
=> true

> a {|v|v}
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):14
NoMethodError (undefined method `a' for main:Object)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean `(@glob || crawl_dir(@base_dir)).each`?

Comment: @tadman no I didn't, though the proposed solution involves assuring an enumerator is always return, which makes things more simple. But I meant for different methods, which accept a block, not only Enumerators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are using different things which are all called `CSV`.

```
CSV {|v|v}
```

Here, you are calling the method named `CSV` with a block. You get the return value of that method back. Methods such as this are usually used as converters. E.g. there is the `Integer()` method which takes an argument (such as a String) which is converted to an `Integer` object.  Usually, those methods are called the same as the class of object they return.

```
a=CSV
```

Here, you are assigning the value of the `CSV` constant (which is the `CSV` class) to the `a` variable. In your code, you can then either use the `CSV` constant or the `a` variable to refer to the class object.

In these cases where you have the same name refer to different things (a class and a method respectively), Ruby can distinguish which one to call / return based on how you use it. Only of you explicitly and unambiguously call the "thing" (i.e. by passing a block or any other arguments), Ruby will call the method.

In all other cases, if you refer to a thing with a name starting with a capital letter, Ruby expects it to a constant and returns its referred to object (which in this case is the `CSV` class object).

```
a {|v|v}
```

Here, you get an error since Ruby tries to call the method named `a` (which doesn't exist). Even if this would work, the `a` variable is at this point a reference to the `CSV` class (which can't be called directly).

(Note: to call a method whose name you have stored in a variable, you can use the `send` method, e.g. `my_receiver.send(a)`.)

Now, to solve your initial issue, you could create a method object and use it to call the desired method, e.g.

```
method_proc = @glob&.method(:each) || method(:crawl_dir).curry(@base_dir)
method_proc.call do |file|
  puts file
end
```

However, this is not very idiomatic Ruby. Here, method references are seldom carried around (rather than in Javascript or Python where you regularly do this with passed function objects). A more idiomatic implementation in Ruby could be:

```
def handle_file(file)
  puts file
end

if @glob.respond_to(:each)
  @glob.each { |file| handle_file(file) }
else
  crawl_dir(@base_dir) { |file| handle_file(file) }
end
```

Even more idiomatic would be if your `crawl_dir` method would (optionally) return an `Enumerator` object, in which case you could simplify the calling code.

Here, I assume that `@glob` is either `nil` or an `Enumerable` object (such as an `Array` or an `Enumerator` which thus response directly to `each`). This allows us to simplify the code further.

```
def crawl_dir(directory)
  # Return an Enumerator object for the current method invocation if no
  # block was passed, similar to how the standard `Enumerable#each` method
  # works.
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?

  # the rest of the method here...
end

enumerable = @glob || crawl_dir(@base_dir)
enumerable.each do |file|
  puts file
end
```

What happens here is that you either take `@glob` (which we assume to be an `Enumerable` object if it exists, and thus response do `each`) or `crawl_dir(@base_dir)` without a block. From your `crawl_dir` method, you will get then an `Enumerator` object back, which is again an `Enumerable`. You can then loop over this object with `each`. Both of your objects thus have the same return type can can thus be used similarly.

Comment: awesome answer! Small improvement: `@glob&.method(:each)` makes no sense, since all objects have a `.method`, so the `&.` won't prevent the exception. Your last example, is the way to go, imo.

Comment: By the way, I don't like ruby magic, and after I read your post I realized, that I "should" have expected `a=CSV()` as the parenthesis are optional (normally). I wasn't aware of this other behavior. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I assumed that `@glob` is either an `Enumerable` or `nil`. If it is `nil`, `@glob&.method(:each)` will always return `nil` too (since `&.` returns `nil` iff the receiver is `nil` and always calls the method for anything else). If `@glob` can be a different object which might have an `each` method or not, then you have to use a more specific check. However, I'd generally recommend to ensure that a variable doesn't contain too diverse types if possible. If you know that the value always response to some required methods, your code will often become simpler and usually also more correct.

Comment: Hmmm, and now that I'm thinking more about that, if `@glob` is in fact either `nil` or an `Enumerable`, you can also just write it as `(@glob || crawl_dir(@base_dir)).each { |file| ... }`

Comment: yes, small improvement but enhances readability. Please update your last example, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a reference to a method, you can use the [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method. You can then call this method using the [`Method#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-call) method, or the `.()` syntactic sugar:

```rb
require 'csv'

a = method(:CSV)

a.() {|v| v }
#=> #<CSV io_type:$stdout encoding:UTF-8 lineno:0 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"">
```

Comment: Not the nicest, and cannot be mixed with `&.` so that `(@glob&.each || crawl_dir(@base_dir))` has to be written un a few lines. But it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`tap`](https://rubyapi.org/2.7/o/object#method-i-tap) on any object:

```
a.tap do |v|
  p v
end
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, it's just passing the object `a` to the block, not passing the block to the method in a.